# Flash Media Server 3.5 memory usage

Tags: memory, memory-leaks, video-streaming, fms3

My problem is that FMS 3.5 memory grows up during work on generic play on demand video (rtmp streaming). To reproduce I used 100MB flv video in *vod* application in standard configuration server. When I do "seek" 50 times, used memory can grow up at 50MB more. This memory doesn't released by FMSCore process when *vod* application is unloaded. So I assume this is memory leak.

Can someone come up with idea how to handle that?